# Selecting property to access programmatically

Tags: python

Given:

```
import configs

thingToLook = 'value'

channels = configs.value
```

Can I do something like

```
channels = config[thingToLook]
```

which is equivalent to

```
channels = config.value
```

?

If I do

`channels = configs[thingToLook]`

I get:

`TypeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

I am trying to select the property to get from `configs` programmatically so I can set it via a string.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Just added another line to the question

Comment: What is `configs`?

Comment: And no, `config[thingToLook]` is not the same as `config.value`. `thingToLook` is a string. `value` would need to be an attribute of `config`. And `config` would need a `__getitem__` function for `config[thingToLook]` to even work

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield Perhaps your looking for [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, Python differentiates between items (bracket access) and attributes (dot access). Syntax that works for accessing one doesn't (usually) work for accessing the other.

You can use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function to dynamically look up an attribute:

```
getattr(configs, thinkToLook)
```

and optionally set a default if nothing is found:

```
getattr(configs, thinkToLook, False)
```

Answer (score 2):

`config.value` and `config['value']` are not the same. They call different methods of the instance.

`config.value` is the same as `config.__getattr__('value')`.

`config['value']` is the same as `config.__getitem__('value')`.

For more information look at this: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html